# Blazor WASM Hosted : index.html in client --> Index.cshtml in server, but static files no more found

Tags: configuration, blazor, webassembly

In a blazor wasm hosted project, in the file index.html of the client, I wanted to set dynamically the tag , in order to automatically manage debug and release configurations(index.html is only one of the impacted files).

I wanted to inject an IConfiguration instance, and I saw on the net that I could change the type from html to cshtml, the actual file is BlazopApp.cshtml (with its code behind), located in the SERVER PROJECT/Pages folder.

But now I get a 404 error while blazor tries to get the css, js files(e.g. with the css of MudBlazor (a graphical library) :  produces a 404 error, and all the same for the static files.

How can I tell to blazor to search these files in the client project? Is it even possible?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand your question, but I think you want to add static files to your blazor project. You can to this under the wwwroot folder in the index.html file.

[image: Screeshot]

Regards